# Should I use functions or stateless functors?

Tags: c++, function, stl, functor

These 2 piece of code do same thing. And it will be used in sort function as you can see.
Which is better? I usually write latter one. But I saw some coders do it like former one.

```
struct val_lessthan : binary_function<pair<string,int>, pair<string, int>, bool>
{
    bool operator() (const pair<string,int>& x, const pair<string,int>& y) const
    {
        return x.second < y.second;
    }
} val_lt;
```

and

```
bool val_lt(const pair<string,int>& x, const pair<string,int>& y) 
{
    return x.second < y.second;
}
```

Will use it like:

```
std::sort(wordvector.begin(), wordvector.end(), val_lt);
```

Comment: The simplest one that does the job is the best.

Comment: You haven't mention with regard to which criteria the alternatives should be judged. There are several situations in which either is "better" than the other one... But in general, yes, take the simpler one. Don't forget the c++1x lambdas if considering either alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use functors over functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451866/why-use-functors-over-functions)

Answer (score 8):

The reason you see some people prefer the first version is that functors can be trivially inlined.

When you pass a functor to `std::sort`, the functor type is known to the function, and so the exact function to call is also known at compile-time, and can be trivially inlined.

With a plain function, what `std::sort` really sees is just a function pointer, and at compile-time that says nothing about *which* function it points to. So that can't be inlined unless the compiler performs some fairly extensive flow analysis to see where the pointer came from *in this specific call*. And it will certainly do that optimization in a small example like yours, but if the functor/function pointer was passed in as a function argument from somewhere else, for example, or it was read from an intermediate data structure before being passed to `std::sort`, then, the compiler might not be able to inline the function pointer version, and so it would end up slower.

Answer (score 6):

The first one is called a *function object* and is useful if you need to pass any context information to the comparison function. The standalone function only gets `x` and `y` and doesn't have the opportunity to carry along any context.

In the specific instance above, the two ways of writing the comparison function are roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably prefer the first as a rule, but would generally prefer to use a template:

```
template <class T>
struct val_lessthan : binary_function<pair<pair<T, T>, bool> {
    bool operator()(T const &x, T const &y) const { 
       return x.second < y.second;
    }
};
```

Use of `.second` limits the degree of genericity, but you still get a little (e.g., if memory serves, `boost::tuple` provides a `.first` and `.second` for tuples of two elements. As a rule, being a template gives a little better assurance that the compiler will be able to generate the code inline, so if you care about efficiency, it might help a little (or it might not, but is unlikely to ever cause any harm).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to **also** call the function in other part of your code, and not passed as a functor, prefer the function form. For example you would prefer:

```
if (val_lt(a,b))
{
//...
}
```

to

```
if(val_lessthan()(a,b))
{
// ...
}
```

Otherwise when choosing the functor form, you'd better call with an unnamed functor object. That is:

```
std::sort(wordvector.begin(), wordvector.end(), val_lesstthan());
```

instead of:

```
val_lesstthan named;
std::sort(wordvector.begin(), wordvector.end(), named);
```

Unnaming parameters and return values easily enables the compiler to perform optimization. It refers to a global concept known as RVO (Return Value Optimization). In that case it will probably free your code from one copy construction.

Comment: Baumes: actually, given that the object is stateless, the compiler would probably elide the construction itself completely.

Comment: @Matthieu M. thank you, did not considered this at all. Coming from Sophia? I studied there .. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, choose the simplest which works for your particular case. In this case, choose second over the first.

Answer (score -2):

Both will be equally fast. Almost negligible difference.

When you use functor, it means the function `operator()` has three parameters in the code generated by the compiler, first paramater is a pointer to the `val_lt` object itself, and the second and third parameters are the parameters which you've mentioned in the signature. Something like this:

```
//the possible code generated by the compiler!
bool operator() (val_lessthan *_this, const pair<string,int>& x, const pair<string,int>& y) const
              //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ note this!
{
    return x.second < y.second;
}
```

Comment: except that the operator() in the functor is inlined