# Functor or boolean comparator

Tags: c++, function, boolean, overloading, functor

What should I use? bool compare or sCompare() functor? And why?
Are there some differences between using this two options?

```
struct Dog
{
    int m_age{};
    int m_weigt{};
};

bool compare(const Dog& a, const Dog& b)
{
    return a.m_age > b.m_age;
}

struct sCompare
{
    bool operator()(const Dog& a, const Dog& b)
    {
        return a.m_age > b.m_age;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Dog> dogs{ Dog{1,20}, Dog{2,10}, Dog{3,5}, Dog{10,40} };
    //sort(begin(dogs), end(dogs), compare); this
    //sort(begin(dogs), end(dogs), sCompare()); or this

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's for use at a single place in the code: neither. Use a lambda instead.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Should I use functions or stateless functors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521898/should-i-use-functions-or-stateless-functors) (although it's super old question, still using `std::binary_function`)

Comment: Also related: [Why use functors over functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451866/why-use-functors-over-functions)

Comment: Supposing I have to use it not at a single place in my code. Should I use lambda anyway?

Comment: `operator()` should be `const`. Otherwise there's no difference.

Comment: @Originalnickname I'm a hater of code duplication, but for a simple `X>Y` I could be talked into repeating the lambda because I won't have to run off to read some other part of the file (or another file) for the definition of the functor. That said, repeating the lambda is a perfect opportunity to <expletive deleted> up and have one with `>` and the other with `<`. You've just seen how easy it is to do that by mistake.

Comment: @user4581301 That makes sense. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two comparators result in opposite ordering (`<` vs `>`). Other than that the biggest difference is that you cannot define a function within a function, but you can define a type in a function. Moreover, lambda expressions offer straightforward syntax to do that:

```
int main()
{
    vector<Dog> dogs{ Dog{1,20}, Dog{2,10}, Dog{3,5}, Dog{10,40} };
    sort(begin(dogs), end(dogs), [](const Dog& a,const Dog& b){ return a.m_age < b.m_age;});
    // or 
    auto comp = [](const Dog& a,const Dog& b){ return a.m_age < b.m_age;}
    sort(begin(dogs), end(dogs),comp); 

}
```

Comment: Yes, right, that was a mistake, The two comparators  should be > and > .

Comment: That means I shouldn't ever use functors or functions in this case?

Comment: @Originalnickname The lambda expression is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for a functor. Usually a functor is preferable to a function because of versatility and better optimization opportunities.

Comment: @user4581301, Thank you very much!

Comment: If declaring the compare function as a global adds value somewhere else in your project then maybe you could do it. You could instead add an operator < or an inline friend compare() function to your Dog class, but again, only if that adds value to some other part of your code. The lambda is the c++11 way to inject 1-off functors.